# How to Hide Android Application from Task Manager/ not recent apps tab

Tags: java, android, taskmanager, supportmapfragment

I'm using a SG Note 4 and when I open the Google Maps app and then go to task manager it never shows up, it does when you go to settings, applications, cached..., how can I achieve the same with my app. Im using a map fragment and when moving the camera the cache increases and increases, I imagine people with little knowledge going to task manager and seeing my app using 500mb of ram might end up getting scared and kill it, or worse uninstalling it. Maybe not all manufacturers give users this option but for those that do how can I do this if it's even possible thanks!!

Comment: You are assuming people with little knowledge will open the task manager?

Comment: @cricket_007 well on the note 4 you just click the recent apps button and the task manager button appears right in front of your eyes

Comment: But your app should be designed to work on all devices, not just Samsung devices.

Comment: @cricket_007 sure that;s what I'm doing